Service server never calls callback
I am trying to test a service with a small python script. The type used is std_srvs/srv/Empty.
My minimal service server looks like this:
from std_srvs.srv import Empty

import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node

class MinimalService(Node):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('myService')
        self.srv = self.create_service(Empty, '/test', self.empty_callback2)
        self.get_logger().info('Init server')
    def empty_callback(self, request, response):
        self.get_logger().info('Incoming request\n')
        return response
    def empty_callback2(self):
        self.get_logger().info('Incoming request\n')

def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init()

    minimal_service = MinimalService()

    minimal_service.get_logger().info('Spinning server')
    rclpy.spin(minimal_service)

    minimal_service.get_logger().info('Closing server')
    rclpy.shutdown()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

When I run it (using either callback method when creating the service), I get:
python3 test.py 
[INFO] [1716999477.664598476] [myService]: Init server
[INFO] [1716999477.665053776] [myService]: Spinning server

The topic exists when (and only when) the service is running:
ros2 service type /test
std_srvs/srv/Empty

But while I can call it, no reply of any kind seems to be received
ros2 service call /test std_srvs/Empty {}
requester: making request: std_srvs.srv.Empty_Request()


The terminal blocks. The same blocking behavior is encountered when creating a small service client in python, and if the call is made through the c libraries.
My best guess is that the spinning is not processing the created service, and I have made a simple mistake, but I am stumped.

I have further narrowed the problem down to containerization. If the service is started in a docker (ros:humble) with --network host and called from another docker (ros:humble) likewise with --network host the issue is present. Also for a similar service written in c++.
If the service caller is in the same terminal/docker container, it works.

It seems like you got the service call working on localhost. To accomplish this between 2 computers on the same network, there may be some configuration in ROS2 needed. Let me know if this documentation on ROS2 Dynamic Discovery helps.
